# Attempting to append a value to a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Trying to append a value to a dictionary

```
public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]

   var parameters: Parameters = [
        "username" : username,
        "first_name" : firstName,
        "last_name" : lastName,
        "profession" : profession
    ]
    if let imageURl = imageUrl {
        parameters[4] = ["image_url" : imageUrl]
    }
```

I get back ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' at line `parameters[4] = ["image_url" : imageUrl]`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should access `parameters` dictionary by its `String` key, i.e. `"image_url"`, not by its index 4:

```
if let imageURl = imageUrl {
    parameters["image_url"] = imageUrl
}
```